# Android class.getMethod not working on Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-2.3-gingerbread

```
final Method method = this.getClass().getMethod("sort", View.class);
```

throws a MethodNotFoundException *only* on Android 2.3 devices (higher Android versions return the method). This is what Android uses to handle xml onClicks, which means all of them are crashing in my app on 2.3 devices. However,

```
final Method method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("sort", View.class);
```

Successfully returns the method.

Here is the method (which is in the same class as the above calls):

```
public void sort(final View v){
    //Stuff
}
```

Comment: I cannot see a difference between the two code `getMethod()` code snippets. The prose suggests that they should be different. Also, if people comment on your question, perhaps you should engage with them, rather than deleting the question, as you appear to have done with your earlier inquiry in this area.

Comment: The latter was supposed to say `getDeclaredMethod()`. Upon looking further into my previous inquiry, `isAccessible()` returned false regardless of API version, but `getMethod()` nonetheless still works on the higher APIs. It was an incorrect portrayal of the problem.

Comment: That's rather strange. Have you tried this experiment with the entire body of `sort()` commented out, so the method is empty. Also, did you answer @fadden's earlier question: "What does your class hierarchy look like? I vaguely remember something being fixed in the way accessibility worked with certain inheritance arrangements."

Comment: Commenting out the method changed nothing. AppCompatActivity > Activity A > B > C > D > E > Activity F. The Activity Running is Activity F, and that is where the method is.

Comment: "Commenting out the method changed nothing" -- phooey. I was hoping that perhaps the problem was that you were referencing something that did not exist in Android 2.3 in a way that Dalvik could not handle.

Comment: Unfortunately this is happening across all of my public methods (that none of them can be found with getMethod, they can still be called in a normal fashion). But it's only manifesting itself as a problem with (all of) my onClicks.